# Keep one painted object in a JPanel while painting another object (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a 9x9 grid that can paint itself, a rectangle that can paint itself, and a constructor that allows for movement of the rectangle with the arrow keys. However, I cannot figure out how to keep the grid on-screen at the same time the rectangle is moving around. Ultimately, I'll want the rectangle to be able to act as navigation of the grid by going right one square when the user presses right, etc.

From what I can tell, the entire JPanel is redone whenever paint() is called, meaning that one way to do it would be to repaint every single line whenever a key is pressed, but that seems excessive. Any other way? As it is, painting the rectangle at all causes the grid to be painted over.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestDoubleObject extends JFrame
{

    private Color ourRectColor = new Color(28,222,144);
    private int ourRectWidth = 50;
    private int ourRectHeight = 50;

    private Point ourRecLocation = new Point(150,150);


    public class Rectangle
    {
        protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d)
        {
                g2d.setColor(ourRectColor);
                g2d.fillRect(ourRecLocation.x, ourRecLocation.y, ourRectWidth, ourRectHeight);
        }

    } // Rectangle class


    public class OurRectangle extends JPanel
    {

        private Rectangle capableRectangle;

        public OurRectangle()
        {
            capableRectangle = new Rectangle();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

            capableRectangle.paint(g2d);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    } // OurRectangle class


    public class CoreGrid
    {
        protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d)
        {

            g2d.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));

            // Draw Horizontal Lines

            for(int i=100;i<=640;i+=60)
                g2d.drawLine(100,i,640,i);


            // Draw Vertical Lines

            for(int i=100;i<=640;i+=60)
                g2d.drawLine(i,100,i,640);

        }

    } // CoreGrid class


    public class OurCoreGrid extends JPanel
    {
        private CoreGrid capableCoreGrid;

        public OurCoreGrid()
        {
            capableCoreGrid = new CoreGrid();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

            capableCoreGrid.paint(g2d);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    } // OurCoreGrid class


    KeyStroke pressRight = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
    KeyStroke pressLeft = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");
    KeyStroke pressUp = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP");
    KeyStroke pressDown = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN");

    OurRectangle recToWorkWith = new OurRectangle();
    OurCoreGrid gridToWorkWith = new OurCoreGrid();


    public TestDoubleObject()
    {

        InputMap inputMap = recToWorkWith.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = recToWorkWith.getActionMap();


        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ourRecLocation.x += 20;
                recToWorkWith.repaint();
            }
        };

        inputMap.put(pressRight, "rightAction");
        actionMap.put("rightAction",rightAction);


        Action leftAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ourRecLocation.x -= 20;
                recToWorkWith.repaint();
            }
        };

        inputMap.put(pressLeft, "leftAction");
        actionMap.put("leftAction",leftAction);


        Action downAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ourRecLocation.y += 20;
                recToWorkWith.repaint();
            }
        };

        inputMap.put(pressDown, "downAction");
        actionMap.put("downAction",downAction);


        Action upAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ourRecLocation.y -= 20;
                recToWorkWith.repaint();
            }
        };

        inputMap.put(pressUp, "upAction");
        actionMap.put("upAction",upAction);



        add(gridToWorkWith);

        add(recToWorkWith);



        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,800);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(

        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new TestDoubleObject();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "From what I can tell, the entire JPanel is redone whenever paint() is called" You're correct.  You should be overriding the paintComponent method of a JPanel.  If you want the grid to show over the rectangle, draw the rectangle first, then the grid. It's much easier to redraw the entire JPanel for each frame of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one way to do it would be to repaint every single line whenever a key is pressed, but that seems excessive.

That is exactly the way painting works. Swing is double buffered so you will not notice a painting problem.

However, that is not your current problem.

> I cannot figure out how to keep the grid on-screen at the same time the rectangle is moving around

The default layout manager for the content pane of a JFrame is the BorderLayout. When you add a component to a BorderLayout and don't specify a constraint, the BorderLayout.CENTER is assumed.

```
add(gridToWorkWith);
add(recToWorkWith);
```

So, with the above code you are attempting to add two components to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. However only the last component added is managed by the BorderLayout, meaning the first component will have a size of (0, 0) so it is never painted.

Swing components have a parent/child relationship, so if you want the rectangle to paint on top of the grid then you need add the rectangle to the grid, the same way you add the grid to the frame.

So the code might be something like:

```
gridToWorkWith.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
gridToWorkWith.add( recToWorkWith );
add(gridToWorkWith);
//add(recToWorkWith);
```

However that still won't work because by default a JPanel is opaque, so you would not see the grid because the rectangle paints over top of it. So you need to make the rectangle non-opaque:

```
recToWorkWith.setOpaque( false );
```

Nice to see that you are using Key Bindings. One suggestion would be to create an Action with parameter to control the movement of the rectangle. So the two parameters would be the x/y change in location.

For an example of this approach check out the `MotionAction` found in the `MotionWithKeyBindings` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). Your four Actions can easily be replaced for 4 instances of the same Action by using different parameters. You could even create a diagonal movement.